# Upload and parse csv in Google App Engine using blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, blobstore

I'm trying to write a simple Google gwt Java-application running on AppEngine.

I've created a jsp Upload form to upload a *.csv File:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>

<%
   BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/HelloWorld/ImportHandlerServlet")   %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <input type="file" name="importCSV">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the server side I wrote a new servlet that should convert the uploaded CSV file to an associated array using openCSV:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class ImportHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();  
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> bkList = blobs.get("importCSV");
        BlobKey blobKey = bkList.get(0);
        BlobstoreInputStream blobStream = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(blobStream));

        //Print out first line to check if BufferedReader is empty
        out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());

        //New CSVReader object reading from bufferedReader
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(bufferedReader);

        //Add csv-Fields to two-dimensional array 
        List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();
        String output[][] =  rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]);

        out.println(output.length);
    }
}
```

If I upload a file the bufferedReader prints out the first line of the it. Therefore the bufferedReader isn't empty but the Array doesn't contain any values.

Does anyone see a possible solution?

Comment: Do you see correct values if you try `out.println(csvReader.readNext())` before `readAll`?

Comment: If I try `out.println(csvReader.readNext())` it prints out `[Ljava.lang.String;@1fb04ae`. This isn't a correct value.

Comment: I figured out that if I add `bufferedReader.readLine();` before the CSVReader initialization, it works but the first line gets (logically) discarded and after about 1000 rows it stops adding following lines to the array.

Comment: You can process data line by line. If do need to represent this data in an array of arrays, for some reason, you can build it line by line too.